# Joomla : Which module is this part of?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.6

I am working on Joomla 1.5 right now and was wondering if there is a way to figure out, from the UI, on which module this is part of ? Eg, there is a picture viewer on the home page and I want to know which module is triggering it.

I do it the hard way no, where I goto all modules and check if each had anything to do with it. But was wondering if there is an easier, faster way.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Joomla 1.5 you can simply add ?tp=1 to the url to force the system to show you the template positions. You should *just* about be able to make out the name of the position in question. From there go to the module manager and filter the list by position.

It shouldn't be too difficult to figure out - the module will have rotator, slideshow or similar in its name/type.

It is probably set to show on the home menu item only too.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is an issue with most CMS - Drupal, Wordpress, and Joomla included. And it can be very frustrating. My approach is normally:

1. Search the module listing for something likely. So, in your example, I'd search for 'picture', 'viewer' 'gallery', etc. and, hopefully, a likely-looking modue would turn up in the listing. Usually, viewing its settings screen makes it obvious whether that module is the relevant one or not.
2. If that fails, I usually look at the source (easiest with firebug), and identify something that is likely to be fairly unique - e.g. a class name or a specific attribute in the markup. Once I have that, I resort to find/grep on the command line to identify the origin.

If you find yourself with a *lot* of extensions, and this becomes a regular problem, you could think about modifying templates to include a comment that identifies their module.